# jQuery syntax showing error

Tags: jquery

```
 $("#txtName,#txtEmail,#txtComment").blur(function check()
        if( $(this).val()== ""){
            $(this).val()="Please Fill in this Required Field!";
    });
```

Please am having error with the above code please help me correct it. Thanks

Comment: Make sure that when posting a question because of an error, that you post both the code and *the error*.

Comment: You're missing an opening curly brace on line 1.

Comment: Thanks @ Alex Lynham

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not correct ,try this

```
 $("#txtName,#txtEmail,#txtComment").blur(function check()
    {
        if( $(this).val()== ""){
            $(this).val()="Please Fill in this Required Field!";
    });
```

2 things you should try is,you can keep a anonymous function here, and use `on` event.

```
  $("#txtName,#txtEmail,#txtComment").on('blur',function(){
            if( $(this).val()== ""){
                $(this).val()="Please Fill in this Required Field!";
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mistake 1:** you cannot call check function like this and you missed close braces for if statement

**Mistake 2:** Actually you assigned text value is wrong.

append the text value like **.val(text)**

```
$(this).val("Please Fill in this Required Field!");
```

**Finally your code be**

```
$("#txtName,#txtEmail,#txtComment").blur(function() {
     if($.trim($(this).val()) == ""){
      $(this).val('Please Fill in this Required Field!');
      }
 });
```

or

```
$("#txtName,#txtEmail,#txtComment").blur(check);

function check() {
  if($.trim($(this).val()) == ""){
   $(this).val('Please Fill in this Required Field!');
 }
}
```